# Julia: How can we compute the adjoint or classical adjoint (Linear Algebra)?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

I wan to compute the classical adjoint in `Julia 1.0`

For this I copied the matrix given as an example in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

```
julia> B = [-3 2 -5; -1 0 -2; 3 -4 1]
3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 -3   2  -5
 -1   0  -2
  3  -4   1
```

That seems to me to compute the transpose of `B` and not its adjoint. Instead, we should get this (from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)):

and tried to get its adjoint using the `adjoint()` function which is mentionned in the Julia documentation [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/LinearAlgebra/) despite that the doc does not specifically said what this function does

```
julia> adjoint(B)
3×3 Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}:
 -3  -1   3
  2   0  -4
 -5  -2   1
```

Instead I want to get this:

[image]

In Matlab I get indeed:

```
>> adjoint(B)

ans =

   -8.0000   18.0000   -4.0000
   -5.0000   12.0000   -1.0000
    4.0000   -6.0000    2.0000
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Julia's adjoint is defined as the transpose of the complex conjugate of the input matrix.  However, you seem to want the **adjugate** matrix:

> The adjugate has sometimes been called the "adjoint", but today the "adjoint" of a matrix normally refers to its corresponding adjoint operator, which is its conjugate transpose.

You can compute the adjugate matrix by inverting, and then multiplying by the determinant:

```
julia> det(B) * inv(B)
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -8.0  18.0  -4.0
 -5.0  12.0  -1.0
  4.0  -6.0   2.0
```

Thanks to @Antoine Levitt and @Syx Pek on the Julia Slack for giving the suggestion of inverting and multiplying by determinant.

---

Original answer:

The adjugate matrix seems to be the transpose of the matrix of cofactors.  Below is a naïve implementation of finding cofactors:

```
# import Pkg; Pkg.add("InvertedIndices")
using InvertedIndices # for cleaner code, you can remove this if you really want to.
function cofactor(A::AbstractMatrix, T = Float64)
           ax = axes(A)
           out = similar(A, T, ax)
           for col in ax[1]
               for row in ax[2]
                   out[col, row] = (-1)^(col + row) * det(A[Not(col), Not(row)])
               end
           end
           return out
       end
```

Then, to find the adjugate, you only need to transpose (`transpose(cofactor(B))`).

The answer is:

```
julia> cofactor(B, Float64) |> transpose
3×3 Transpose{Float64,Array{Float64,2}}:
 -8.0  18.0  -4.0
 -5.0  12.0  -1.0
  4.0  -6.0   2.0
```

which is equivalent to what Matlab gives.

Edit: @Antoine Levitt on the Julia slack pointed out that this is essentially a rescaled inverse matrix, so if you figure out the scaling factor, you can just do `inv(B) * scaling_factor` (in the case of this matrix, it's 6).

Comment: I get the error `ERROR: UndefVarError: Not not defined`, where is `Not` coming from? I just realized its in `InvertedIndex` package.